# Users keep getting disconnected

Tags: razor, webmatrix

So i get users getting disconnected with no reason (or better i don't know the reason).

On the login page i make a session:

```
Session.Add("UserProfile", username);
```

On the landing page

```
 string userNames = Session["UserProfile"] as string;
 if(userNames == null){
   Response.Redirect("~/default.cshtml");
}
```

On the Webconfig i've tried this

```
  <sessionState cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="240"> </sessionState>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="252400" executionTimeout="1200" />
  <authentication mode="Forms"> <forms timeout="525600" slidingExpiration="true" /></authentication>
```

And the thing is... On the landing page i got a list where users can choose an id, enter on it and each have id have a form that the user can edit.

But very often when the user submit the form, he's redirected to the login page.

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have specified a forms authentication timeout value but you aren't actually using Forms Authentication so that won't have any effect. Sessions can be ended by App Pool recycling on the web server so it is perfectly possible for users to lose their session and therefore fail your landing page test. That will result in them being redirected to the home page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mike. But i think i cannot change anything on the server, we have a lot of aplications running. Perhaps the best option is to try using Forms Authentication. Do you think that using Forms Authentication my problem can be fixed ?

Comment: Yes, on the basis that the forms authentication cookie that keeps the user logged in will persist for as long as you specify, regardless of sessions. If you are using WebMatrix, perhaps you should look at the WebSecurity helper. It does all the hard work for you.

Comment: Ok will try it. Thanks a lot for your time Mike.